# Is SELECT COUNT(*) unreliable in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm running the following queries in a SQL Server 2000 database I inherited:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 *
FROM tblTransactionHistory
WHERE TransactionTypeID = 2 AND AccountNumber IS NULL

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tblTransactionHistory
WHERE TransactionTypeID = 2 AND AccountNumber IS NULL
```

The first query returns an empty record set.  The second query returns a count of 3,543,203.  I don't believe the count.  As further verification, the following query returns only non-NULL account numbers.

```
SELECT
   AccountNumber,
   COUNT(*)
FROM tblTransactionHistory
WHERE TransactionTypeID = 2
GROUP BY AccountNumber
```

I also checked `DBCC USEROPTIONS` and verified that the isolation level is set to `read committed`.  I have not encountered problems with `SELECT COUNT(*)` on SQL Server before.  Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: This seems relevant. It was fixed in SP 4 for Server 2000. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/814509

Comment: What @@version are you on? Is it pre that fix? Do you get a parallel or serial execution plan? Any corruption detected? What do the execution plans look like? Accessing same or different indexes?

Comment: Joe and Martin, thanks for the help!  That is likely the problem.  I checked, and I'm only on service pack 2.  I'll get operations to apply the latest service pack if I can't get this moved to SQL Server 2014 as quickly as I'm hoping.  Thanks!